# Analyzing an ethernet cable for low negotiating speed

Tags: ethernet, cable, gigabit-ethernet, analysis

I'd like to find out why my cat 6a refuses to negotiate 1000 speed.

I have a 15 meter long U/FTP CCS cat 6a Ethernet cable installation.

I have analysed the cable with a multimeter and each strand (white, blue, green etc) measures around 3.6 ohm resistance. I cannot find any bleeding in the same test, each signal is isolated to each strand tested. I also have checked the signal order is correct following A standard wiring.

When I try to enforce 1000 full or half duplex I loose connection.

```
sudo ethtool -s enx00 autoneg off speed 1000 duplex full
```

Automatically, it negotiate to 100 full duplex.

Replacing the route with a separate patch cable the two points negotiate 1000 full duplex, thus isolating the problem with the ethernet cable installation.

I'd like to ask for some input to understand the problem and perhaps some help to explain a bit missing theory before I go out and buying a new cable. I would feel more comfortable after I understand the problem better.

Comment: Ethernet cable certification is more complicated than continuity and resistance: https://www.bluejeanscable.com/networkcablereports.htm

Comment: Thanks, I won't bother going there then, and just buy a new cable instead.